# Disable Layout Scaling WinUI 3.0

Tags: winapi, winui-3

How do I do the equivalent of UWP XAML UI's ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling(true) in a WinUI 3.0 Desktop application?

Comment: According to the Doc: [Mapping UWP APIs and libraries to the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/api-mapping-table)

It seems that there is no a similar method to ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling in winui3.

I suggest you could post the issue to WinUI3 forum, the WinUI team is actively answering questions on GitHub here: [microsoft-ui-xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)

Comment: I started a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinUI 3.0 Application UI's are already adjusted for DPI Scaling, but media is not. If your screen size is 1080p and media is 1080p, but scaling is 125%, the media will be larger than the screen size, but the app will be properly adjusted. If you have a lot of media, it might be worth scaling the root frame.

To do any scaling do the following and either a) target each media piece itself or b) adjust the scaling of your entire app(root frame).

To compensate for any scaling, set the `x:Name` of the target to be scaled; like a root frame, or an image in Xaml i.e. `x:Name="root"`. Where you target the scaling depends on what you are scaling and the separation of your Window, Frame, Page. It's easiest to target the root element or image in the Loaded override function of the Page. If you want to adjust the Frame, it will have to be the root element of the Window and you'll probably target the overloaded function OnNavigated. It all depends on the level of separation between Window, Frame, and Page in Xaml. The Xaml has to be loaded before scaling can occur, because the TypeInfo has to be allocated to the MetaData Tree.

Scale using `root().Scale(float3)`. To adjust scale based on the scaling of your device, call `root().XamlRoot()` and get the rasterization scale:

`float rastScale = (float)root().XamlRoot().RasterizationScale()`

Then set the scale with:

`root().Scale({(1/rastScale), (1/rastScale), 1.0f})`

When the documentation says XamlRoot, you are actually calling the x:Name, not some static plumbing. You cannot use `this->XamlRoot()` as this returns null. You cannot `x:Name` the Xaml Class to get `XamlRoot()`.